# Connect to hidden Wifi AP with wpa-supplicant?

Tags: command-line, networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I have a headless Debian machine, with a Wifi dongle connected. I used to hide the Wifi AP, but now I can't.

If I unhide it, some lines in the /etc/network/interfaces will allow me to connect:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid <name>
        wpa-psk <hex/raw pwd>
```

If I hide the AP, add this line, then restart the interface, it won't work (DHCP gets no IP):

```
wpa-ap-scan 2
```

I've not found official documentation about the /etc/network/interfaces config.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I've found out a solution, just an other line (previous not needed: <strike>wpa-ap-scan</strike>)

```
wpa-scan-ssid 1
```

I've not really found it in any documentation... just in a forum post.

Comment: I found this by guessing too, I used `wpa-scan_ssid 1`. Also works.

Answer (score 4):

> I've not found official documentation about the /etc/network/interfaces config.

You can find the documentation at `/usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/README.Debian.gz`. Under `Chapter 4: Troubleshooting` there's a section titled `Hidden ssids`:

> In order to be able to associate to hidden ssids, please try to set the option 'ap_scan=1' in the global section, and 'scan_ssid=1' in your network block section of your wpa_supplicant.conf file. If you are using the managed mode, you can do so by these stanzas:
>
> ```
> iface eth1 inet dhcp
>     wpa-ap-scan 1
>     wpa-scan-ssid 1
>     # ... additional options for your setup
> ```